# $push removes all other fields in the document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I try to update a field in a collection that contains an array with $push. Instead of adding the value, the document gets replaced by a document containing only _id. If I do the update in the mongo-console it works.

Here's the code: (Serverside)

```
Meteor.methods({
    dismiss: function (jobId,userId) {
        Jobs.update(jobId, {$push : {dismissed: userId}},{validate: false},function(){});  
    },
});
```

The document in mongodb before looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "MBfQ39BsKwqspLLEL", "title" : "Derniset edolar ingreadcomi permaap manthe soi ti.", "description" : "Siter tersion ingtery enlaringvi disicgen yma.", "wage" : 10, "wagePeriod" : "hour", "currency" : "Euro", "image" : "xGDcPNXjn7kpa2mv2", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-18T06:40:47.575Z") }
```

And after the operation it looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "MBfQ39BsKwqspLLEL" }
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking here, can you update with a more concise question?

Comment: Weird. Can you set up a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/) with your code and the issue?

Comment: Hard to set up a MeteorPad, since the app has gotten quite big already.
I try to update the question to be more precise.

Comment: Eventually I created a method for updating the collection to gain full permission. However there is a new problem: With $push the targeted document gets replaced by a new empty document. I thought $push and $addToSet do not replace the whole document?